# What should I use instead of amCharts for charts and graphs on wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, graph, charts

I have a question that's been unanswered for a couple of days (has that even happened before?) and am now looking for alternate solutions. Here is the other question in case of interest: [linegraph on wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346683/linegraph-on-wp7)

As the title mentions; what should I use instead of amCharts for drawing charts on wp7? I need to be able to draw one graph on three pivot items and it's supposed to be a linegraph.

Any ideas?

Comment: one graph on three items? or 3 graphs, each on a separate pivot item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of questions about available charting libraries have been asked before.
See:

[Windows Phone 7 Charting/Graphing Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624876/windows-phone-7-charting-graphing-controls)

[Charting Library for Windows Phone 7 with Zooming & Panning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069617/charting-library-for-windows-phone-7-with-zooming-panning)

[Plotting library for Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788152/plotting-library-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight)

[How can I draw a nice graph like the HTC 'Stocks' app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957485/how-can-i-draw-a-nice-graph-like-the-htc-stocks-app)

[how would I implement realtime graphing in Silverlight/WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268649/how-would-i-implement-realtime-graphing-in-silverlight-wp7)